# Event Confirmation Window - Formatting Issue: Text not wrapping

Tags: civievent, joomla, confirmation, textarea

In our current event confirmation page, there is a text formatting issue (does not wrap) that I've not been able to resolve. Is there a simple fix for this?

[image: textwrapping]

Comment: Would be useful to know what version of CiviCRM, what CMS and probably what theme you are using.

Comment: You could try some other themes for 'front end civicrm', as Mick says, that is likely the issue.

Comment: Hello - We're using Civi - 5.42.1; CMS - Joomla 3.10.3

Comment: @petednz-fuzion can you plase explain what you mean 'front end civicrm'? I am not familiar... Thank you!

Comment: Hi Jennifer i don't know joomla integration at all, but with Drupal integration you are able to specify what Drupal theme should be used when a civicrm form is available to the public (which is what i meant by front end but agree it isn't a super clear term). i will add Joomla tag to this in case there are joomla folk tracking it

Answer (score 1):

I'm no Joomla expert, but part of the problem is that you have some very long names for your custom fields. One way round this would be to use much shorter names for the fields and add more detail about the information you are asking for in the field pre help in the profile you are using for the event registration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the CSS property `white-space` is set to "nowrap" on the label. If not that, some other CSS class or property is messing that up. If you can share the URL, I can take a look at your site, and give you a more precise answer :)
As Mick Kahn pointed out, you could consider shortening the labels, and placing the longer text into field pre or post help.

Comment: Yes, thank you, we've figured this out and resolved!